# Can't Use generator in nodejs typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, generator

here is my typscript code -

```
export default class CModel{
    CName:string;
    [Symbol.iterator]: function* () { 
        yield 1;
      }
```

}

here is my error list-

1. cModel[Symbol.iterator] is not a function.
2. Can not find name
   function.

Answer (score 1):

`[Symbol.iterator]: ...` designates a type, doesn't assign a value. `function* () { ... }` is not a type, it's actual function.

If the intention is to assign `Symbol.iterator` property on class instance, it should be:

```
export default class CModel{
    CName:string;

    [Symbol.iterator] = function* () { 
        yield 1;
    }  
}
```